# OKhttp PUT example

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, android-networking, androidhttpclient

My requirement is to use `PUT`, send a header and a body to server which will update something in the database.

I just read [okHttp documentation](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) and I was trying to use their `POST` example but it doesn't work for my use case **(I think it might be because the server requires me to use `PUT` instead of `POST`)**.

This is my method with `POST`:

```
 public void postRequestWithHeaderAndBody(String url, String header, String jsonBody) {


        MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonBody);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .addHeader("Authorization", header)
                .build();

        makeCall(client, request);
    }
```

I have tried to search for okHttp example using `PUT`with no success, if I need to use `PUT`method is there anyway to use okHttp?

I'm using okhttp:2.4.0 (just in case), thanks on any help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change your `.post` with `.put`

```
public void putRequestWithHeaderAndBody(String url, String header, String jsonBody) {


        MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonBody);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .put(body) //PUT
                .addHeader("Authorization", header)
                .build();

        makeCall(client, request);
    }
```

Comment: What if the request doesn't have a body , I mean how to send a put request using OKHttp without a request body ?

Answer (score 5):

### OkHttp Version 2.x

If you're using OkHttp Version 2.x, use the following:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
        .add("Key", "Value")
        .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("http://www.foo.bar/index.php")
    .put(formBody)  // Use PUT on this line.
    .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
    throw new IOException("Unexpected response code: " + response);
}

System.out.println(response.body().string());
```

---

### OkHttp Version 3.x

As OkHttp version 3 replaced `FormEncodingBuilder` with `FormBody` and `FormBody.Builder()`, for versions 3.x you have to do the following:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("message", "Your message")
        .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://www.foo.bar/index.php")
        .put(formBody) // PUT here.
        .build();

try {
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

    // Do something with the response.
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`put`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Request.java#L223) method instead of [`post`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Request.java#L211)

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .put(body) // here we use put
            .addHeader("Authorization", header)
            .build();
```