# How to create or update the search template of elasticsearch through Java code

Tags: java, rest, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-template

I am using following elasticsearch query which I created using `POST /_search/template/search` through Postman

```
{
    "template": {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "paymentAccounts",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "nested": {
                      "path": "accounts",
                      "query": {
                        "bool": {
                          "should": [
                           {
                             "wildcard": {
                              "accounts.person.email.keyword": "*{{smartsearchquerystring}}*"
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "wildcard": {
                                "accounts.description.keyword": "*{{smartsearchquerystring}}*"
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "wildcard": {
                                "accounts.tradeName.keyword": "*{{smartsearchquerystring}}*"
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "wildcard": {
                                "accounts.referenceId.keyword": "*{{smartsearchquerystring}}*"
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
"from" : "{{offset}}",
"size" : "{{limit}}"
}
}
```

Now each time if I want to update the search template I hit the same endpoint through Postman.
I want to create a method in my service such as whenever I want to update that any template just gives params to that method and create or update the template.

How can I do that using Java? or any suggestions regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save your template as JSON somewhere and send a PUT request to ES, 
and your Endpoint should be like below, not the one you used to search:
/_template/{{template name or alias}}

you can use OkHttpClient to send your request more details check below:
[OKhttp PUT example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886172/okhttp-put-example)