# How to use PUT request with okhttp3 in Java?

Tags: java, okhttp, put

I'm very new to this so please be nice. I am trying to make a PUT request to some endpoint in which I need to send that some boolean variable is true or false. I am using okhttp3 with Java 11.

```
final Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(someBaseURL + "/" + obj.getKey() + "/path")
        .build();
    execute(request);
```

This is my code so far and I need to call the endpoint with the following URL:

> *"someBaseURL/obj.key/path?booleanVariable=true"*

So my question is how do I make a `PUT` request that adds this `booleanVariable` with its value being true or false. I tried a very stupid and simple way just adding the `"?booleanVariable=true"` to the `.url()` but then that request is just a `GET` and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886172/okhttp-put-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending data in body then you try this code:

```
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\n\t\"first_param\":\"xxxxxx\"}");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://localhost:8080/api-path?booleanVariable=true")
  .put(body)
  .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

or if you only sending data in params then you should  try below code

```
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\n\t\n}");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://localhost:8080/api-path?booleanVariable=true")
  .put(body)
  .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```